binding storage buffer in rust wgpu
I'm learning rust wgpu. Till now, I am able to send uniform data to shader. Now I want to send storage buffer to shader. But I'm getting following error:
[ERROR wgpu::backend::wgpu_core] Handling wgpu errors as fatal by default
thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\..\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\wgpu-22.1.0\src\backend\wgpu_core.rs:3411:5:
wgpu error: Validation Error

Caused by:
  In Device::create_bind_group_layout, label = 'storage_bind_group_layout'
    Binding 0 entry is invalid
      Features Features(VERTEX_WRITABLE_STORAGE) are required but not enabled on the device


note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\game_of_life_desktop.exe` (exit code: 101)

I'm following this tutorial. It is written for javascript, I'm trying to convert it for rust. I'm sharing code below
        let storage_buffer = device.create_buffer_init(
            &wgpu::util::BufferInitDescriptor {
                // basic initialization
                usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::STORAGE | wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_DST,
            }
        );

        let storage_bind_group_layout = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
            entries: &[
                wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
                    binding: 0, // I have tried to use 0/1 for bind as well, not working
                    visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::VERTEX,
                    ty: wgpu::BindingType::Buffer {
                        ty: wgpu::BufferBindingType::Storage { read_only: false },
                        has_dynamic_offset: false,
                        min_binding_size: None,
                    },
                    count: None,
                }
            ],
        });
  
        let storage_bind_group = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
            layout: &storage_bind_group_layout,
            entries: &[
                wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
                    binding: 1, // I have tried to use 0/1 for bind as well, not working
                    resource: storage_buffer.as_entire_binding(),
                }
            ],
        });

Render code:
            render_pass.set_bind_group(0, &self.uniform_bind_group, &[]);
            render_pass.set_bind_group(1, &self.storage_bind_group, &[]);

Shader code:
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> grid: vec4<f32>; [4.0,4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
@group(0) @binding(1) var<storage> cellState: array<u32>;


Check if adapter.features contains VERTEX_WRITABLE_STORAGE, otherwise you are out of luck with your current device.

If you look at the documentation of Features::VERTEX_WRITABLE_STORAGE it says:

Enables bindings of writable storage buffers and textures visible to vertex shaders.

and

This is a native only feature.

wgpu’s documentation cryptically uses “native” to mean “not web”. So, the thing that is not supported is you asking for a read-write binding here:
ty: wgpu::BufferBindingType::Storage { read_only: false },

But you don’t need to write to the buffer from the vertex shader, so you should set read_only to true.
